# Using namedtuples with existing lists

Tags: python

This is a homework question. I'm pretty sure that I need to use namedtuples.

I have lists of data that looks like this:

```
data = [["first", "last", "info", "info", "info"],["first m.", 
"last", "info", "info", "info"]...]
```

The goal is to create a dictionary of all like lastnames -- ie - group on "Smith". Exclude first names.

```
output = { "last1": [["info","info","info"], 
["info","info","info"]], "last2": [["info","info","info"]]...}
```

This is what I tried:

```
facultyByLastname = defaultdict(list)
    for first, last, info, info, info in facultyData:
         facultyByLastname[last].append(info)
         facultyByLastname[last].append(info)
         facultyByLastname[last].append(info)
```

The output is nearly there, but I question whether I'm using namedtuples this correctly. I'm The output looks like this:

```
output = { "last1" : ["info","info","info","info","info","info"], 
"last2": ["info","info","info"]...}
```

Rather than keeping the data of the individual people in their list, it ungroups them and sticks all data with the same last name in a single list.

I'm stuck and need some help!

Comment: I don't see any use of namedtuples in your code.

Comment: Seems you are using dictionaries, not namedtuples. All keys in a dictionary must be unique. That is, you can't have two keys in a dictionary as `'Smith'`.

Comment: Perhaps you don't want `append`, but just assignment? In which case, you can (should) use an ordinary dict. But in that case, people with the same last name will overwrite each other's information data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need named tuples or a default dictionary for this. The primary problem is the way you are destructuring the list:

```
 for first, last, info, info, info in facultyData:
```

It's not clear what you intend the variable `info` to hold here. Instead you can grab the entire rest of the list with:

```
for first, last, *info in facultyData:
```

Then you can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to make entries in the dictionary if they don't already exist:

```
data = [["first", "last", "info", "info", "info"],["first m.", "last2", "info", "info", "info"], ["first m.", "last", "info", "info", "info"]]

facultyByLastname = {}

for first, last, *info in data:
   facultyByLastname.setdefault(last, []).append(info)
```

​
**Result**

```
{'last': [['info', 'info', 'info'], ['info', 'info', 'info']],
 'last2': [['info', 'info', 'info']]}
```

Comment: Thanks for interpreting my post! This works. Much appreciated